Did Diontae Johnson play vs. Broncos at Week 9 Game of NFL 2024-25 season?
Did Diontae Johnson play vs. Broncos at Week 9 Game?
There was no stat of him and I didn't see the game, so there is no way for me to decide whether he never entered the grounded or he played but just recorded no stats.
